# Driver issue with the USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, driver

I have a *MacBook (2016)* and the first time I plugged in my *USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter* it prompted me to install an update to the driver - I didn't complete the installation at that point.

Now the (same) driver update prompt pops up every time I plugin the adapter - even though I've installed the update (multiple times).

[image]

I suspect that the first (failed) install of the driver update have caused it to prompt on every plugin (?) - is there any way to break this *"loop"*?

Comment: Odd. I have MacBook 2016 and the multi port adapter. It has never done an update prompt.

Comment: @Gilby maybe you got it in a regular OS update? Anyway - pretty annoying prompt to get every time I plugin ;-)

Comment: Mine came with 10.11.4, didn't ask for the USB-C update; since updated to 10.11.5.  Have you tried reapplying 10.11.5 again?

Comment: @Gilby - I finally got it to work - thank you for the re-install suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has (finally) been resolved!

The solution was to:

1. Manually download the `10.11.5` (newest) OSX update from the Apple website and install it
2. Reboot the machine
3. Plug in the USB-C Multiport Adapter
4. Install the suggested update
5. Reboot

(thanks to [Gilby](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/43889/gilby) for suggesting the re-install of the update)

Comment: Pleased you got a solution - and that I helped!

Comment: This didn't work for me. Check @alanning's solution, which worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For those searching I am having this issue with a new 2016 MacBook Pro running sierra v10.12.1.  Multiple Install->Reboot cycles with everything still plugged in but the Multiport Update is not being installed.

[RESOLVED]

UPDATE: 
Your USB-C Power Cord *must* be plugged directly into your multiport adapter (which is plugged into your laptop) when doing the reboot.  Having the adapter plugged into one port, while the power cord is plugged into another of your laptop's ports will not work.

NOTE 1: Working Layout

`Wall power outlet => USB-C Power Adapter => USB-C Power Cord => Multiport Adapter => Laptop`

   (You don't need the external display plugged in.)

NOTE 2: When I first plugged my power cord into the multiport adapter, it displayed some weird behavior where the Driver Install prompt went away and the "charging" icon would show briefly, then disappear.  I restarted my laptop with everything still plugged in and then the Driver Install prompt stayed visible.

You could probably also click the "Install" button before pluggin in the power cord and once the wizard is open, plug in the power cord.  I'd guess the power cord is only required to be plugged into the multiport adapter to give the adapter power during the reboot.

NOTE 3: The time that the install/reboot actually worked, the reboot took a significantly longer time than usual.  Probably about 3 mins.  So if you also experience that then its a good sign.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternative solution:

I had the same issue, kept receiving the same prompt. Each time I installed the update, I restarted the computer. Then one day I walked away after hitting "restart", so it just sat for 5-10min waiting for me to login to FileVault. Eventually the machine just turned off. When I returned and booted the system, no more prompt!

The (alternative) solution was to:

1. Install the update as prompted
2. Restart the computer, but don't log back in
3. Let the log in screen time-out and the system turn itself off
4. Boot the computer back up and log-in as normal

Comment: This didn't work for me. Check @alanning's solution, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem on a 2016 13" Macbook Pro w/o touchbar.  I found a suggestion on Apple's forums to flip over the USB-C cable from the adapter to the laptop.  This made no sense, but I did it anyway while I looked for other answers.  I don't know why, but it worked.  I'm dumbfounded.

I'm running OSX 10.12.2, no pending updates until I plugged the adapter in.  Failed to install the adapter update for three consecutive reboots.  No HDMI or USB plugged in, but with the power adapter connected.  Not sure if this will be helpful to others, but

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved this on a brand-new Macbook Pro. For this update you need to read the release note: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205858 - quote, bold type is mine:

> 2. Plug your USB-C Multiport Adapter into the USB-C port on your Mac. Make sure that your **USB-C Charge Cable is connected to your adapter** and plugged into a power source using your USB-C Power Adapter.
> 3. **Disconnect all external devices** (such as displays, thumb drives, and hard drives) and hard-wired network connections from your USB-C Multiport Adapter.

If you do these two things it works.